# How to add a list to lists within a list, to create lists within lists within a list?

Tags: python, list

Pretty new to Python so if the title isn't confusing enough, I'd appreciate some help. I will able to best explain this using an example of what I'm aiming to achieve.

```
Number = [25, 30, 36]
Ratings = [ [101, 201, 301], [102, 202, 302], [103, 203, 304,] ]

what_i_want = [  [ [101, 25],[201,30],[301,36] ], [ [102,25],[202,25],[302,36] ], [ [103,25],[203,30],[303,36] ]  ]
```

I'm completely stumped on how to do this, I've tried using nested for loops but the list ends up looking like this:

```
list = [ ([101, 201, 301], 25), ([102, 202, 302], 30), ([103, 203, 304,], 36) ]
```

Also, I'm going to be dealing with a very large size of lists, so ways to improve efficiency and speed would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zip` with list comprehension:

```
Number = [25, 30, 36]
Ratings = [ [101, 201, 301], [102, 202, 302], [103, 203, 304,] ]
new_data = [[[a, b] for a, b in zip(i, Number)] for i in Ratings]
```

Output:

```
[[[101, 25], [201, 30], [301, 36]], [[102, 25], [202, 30], [302, 36]], [[103, 25], [203, 30], [304, 36]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for loops as such.

```
Number = [25, 30, 36]
Ratings = [ [101, 201, 301], [102, 202, 302], [103, 203, 304,] ]

list = []
for i in xrange(len(Ratings)):        #Iterate through outer list.
    list.append([])                   #Add new middle list to list.
    for j in xrange(len(Ratings[i])): #Iterate through inner list.
        list[i].append([Ratings[i][j],Number[j]])
```

Output:

```
list = [[[101, 25], [201, 30], [301, 36]], [[102, 25], [202, 30], [302, 36]], [[103, 25], [203, 30], [304, 36]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in one line without importing any module or making it more complex :

just use lambda :

```
Number = [25, 30, 36]
Ratings = [ [101, 201, 301], [102, 202, 302], [103, 203, 304,] ]

print(list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda y,y1:[y,y1],x,Number)),Ratings)))
```

output:

```
[[[101, 25], [201, 30], [301, 36]], [[102, 25], [202, 30], [302, 36]], [[103, 25], [203, 30], [304, 36]]]
```